# MVC .NET Project with LinqToSql- In which project should the local database instance be?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2, local-database

Out of good design practice and organization, in which project should a local development SQL database be in a web based application?

I'm just starting my assignment so I currently have 'CompanyName.Web.UI' and 'CompanyName.Domain' projects setup.  Im using LinqToSql and creating my database from POCOS, meaning I'll have to create some code to generate the DB from my domain model.

I.e.

```
DataContext dc = new DataContext(connString);
dc.GetTable<TableType>();
dc.CreateDatabase();
```

Comment: I like how http://codecampserver.codeplex.com/ lays things out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Express the database file is usually stored in the special `App_Data` folder in the web application and the connection string configured in web.config.